# Apply scale and fade effect to Images together

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using below commands to overlay two images with scaling in video :

```
String command="ffmpeg -i /sdcard/videokit/input.mp4 -loop 1 -i /sdcard/videokit/first.png -loop 1 -i /sdcard/videokit/second.png -filter_complex [1:v]scale='if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'[img1];[2:v]scale='if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'[img2];[0:v][img1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[bkg];[bkg][img2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 -c:a copy -preset ultrafast /sdcard/videokit/output.mp4";

String command2="ffmpeg -i /sdcard/videokit/input.mp4 -loop 1 -t 2 -i /sdcard/videokit/first.png -loop 1 -t 2 -i /sdcard/videokit/second.png -filter_complex [1:v]trim=duration=2,fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=1.5:d=0.5[img1];[2:v]trim=duration=2,fade=in:st=10:d=0.5,fade=out:st=11.5:d=0.5[img2];[0:v][img1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[bkg];[bkg][img2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -preset ultrafast /sdcard/videokit/output.mp4";
```

First command works perfectly but I want to apply fade in fade out effect to both images for certain time.

I have tried with command2 after referring other answers but it doesn't seem to be working, any help would be appreciated!!!

**Aim to achieve** : Basically I have video of 12 seconds, first image has to be appear for first 2 seconds and last image for last 2 seconds with effect.

Comment: @Mulvya   Any help for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
String command2="ffmpeg -i /sdcard/videokit/input.mp4 -loop 1 -t 2 -i /sdcard/videokit/first.png -loop 1 -t 2 -i /sdcard/videokit/second.png -filter_complex "[0]boxblur=enable='lt(t,2)+gt(t,10)'[vid];[1:v]format=rgba,fade=in:st=0:d=0.5:alpha=1,fade=out:st=1.5:d=0.5:alpha=1[img1];[2:v]format=rgba,fade=in:st=0:d=0.5:alpha=1,fade=out:st=1.5:d=0.5:alpha=1,setpts=PTS+10/TB[img2];[vid][img1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[bkg];[bkg][img2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -preset ultrafast -c:a copy /sdcard/videokit/output.mp4";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Its perfect :) and small issue is first image is slightly appearing after 2 seconds?

Comment: Either increase the `t` of the first image slightly, like to `2.5` or decrease the duration of the fade out.

Comment: Yup it worked and my video size is 25mb currently it takes 2-3 minutes to process, can we reduce it?

Comment: Speed? No. Size? Yes - change preset to medium or slow.

Comment: I meant processing time?

Comment: No, ultrafast is fastest possible.

Comment: Okay fine, can we apply blur background behind first and second images when they visible?

Comment: Add `[0]boxblur=enable='lt(t,2)+gt(t,10)'[vid]` to the filter_complex and use `[vid]` for first overlay.

Comment: Can you update your answer with that?

Comment: I have applied rotation to video, can you guide me for images in above command?

Comment: You want to rotate the pics? Which direction?

Comment: Yes pics, I want to rotate pics as per video orientation

Comment: Insert the transpose filter after the format filter for each image. e.g. `transpose=1` for 90 deg clockwise `2` for CCW.

Comment: Okay let me try